# Descontar cantidades en SQL sin usar un cursor (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Necesito descontar o descargar cantidades, tengo una consulta que arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este resultado tengo que ir descargando el saldo en base a la cantidad, la columna a calcular es `descontar`; o sea para un artículo tengo una cantidad de 65 y tres saldos 50, 30 y 10 por lo tanto la columna descontar debería quedar en 50, 15 y 0, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado del *query* lo puse en una tabla y lo copio a continuación:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prueba_descarga](
[articulo] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[cantidad] [DECIMAL](16, 6) NULL,
[lote] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[saldo] [DECIMAL](16, 6) NULL,
[fecha] [DATETIME] NULL,
[descontar] [DECIMAL](16, 6) NULL) 

INSERT [dbo].[prueba_descarga] ([articulo], [cantidad], [lote], [saldo], [fecha], [descontar]) VALUES (N'A0001', CAST(65.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)), N'452', CAST(50.0000000 AS Decimal(22, 7)), CAST(N'2018-06-07T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[prueba_descarga] ([articulo], [cantidad], [lote], [saldo], [fecha], [descontar]) VALUES (N'A0001', CAST(65.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)), N'455', CAST(30.0000000 AS Decimal(22, 7)), CAST(N'2018-06-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[prueba_descarga] ([articulo], [cantidad], [lote], [saldo], [fecha], [descontar]) VALUES (N'A0001', CAST(65.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)), N'456', CAST(10.0000000 AS Decimal(22, 7)), CAST(N'2018-06-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[prueba_descarga] ([articulo], [cantidad], [lote], [saldo], [fecha], [descontar]) VALUES (N'A0002', CAST(20.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)), N'457', CAST(15.0000000 AS Decimal(22, 7)), CAST(N'2018-06-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)))
INSERT [dbo].[prueba_descarga] ([articulo], [cantidad], [lote], [saldo], [fecha], [descontar]) VALUES (N'A0002', CAST(20.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)), N'458', CAST(25.0000000 AS Decimal(22, 7)), CAST(N'2018-06-11T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(0.000000 AS Decimal(16, 6)))
```

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: En tu ejemplo, el "descuento" no parece ir en algún orden lógico...por qué se descuenta primero 50?

Comment: Hola, si eso me falto, el descuento sería por primero por fecha y luego por lote

Comment: Si es primero por fecha, debió descontarse 30 primero entonces?

Comment: Tal cual como decis! lo que pasa que lo hice mentamente y lo hice mal

Comment: y qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: SQL 2014 (12.0.5207.0 SP2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema no es tan sencillo, pero se facilita un poco por el hecho que estés usando SQL Server 2014.

En este caso seguro que hay alguna forma más simple de hacerlo, pero el siguiente código me entrega los resultados correctos

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            aux1 = cantidad - SUM(saldo) OVER(PARTITION BY articulo ORDER BY fecha, lote)
    FROM dbo.prueba_descarga A
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            aux2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY articulo ORDER BY CASE WHEN aux1 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, aux1 DESC) 
    FROM CTE1 A
)
SELECT  articulo,
        cantidad,
        lote,
        saldo,
        fecha,
        descontar = CASE 
                        WHEN aux1 >= 0 THEN saldo
                        WHEN aux1 < 0 AND aux2 = 1 THEN saldo + aux1
                        ELSE 0 
                    END 
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY articulo, fecha, lote
;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13aa0ceb03c8963849efbb8f9410d555) con este código.

Y los resultados son:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ articulo ║ cantidad  ║ lote ║   saldo   ║          fecha          ║ descontar ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ A0001    ║ 65.000000 ║  455 ║ 30.000000 ║ 2018-06-05 00:00:00.000 ║ 30.000000 ║
║ A0001    ║ 65.000000 ║  452 ║ 50.000000 ║ 2018-06-07 00:00:00.000 ║ 35.000000 ║
║ A0001    ║ 65.000000 ║  456 ║ 10.000000 ║ 2018-06-11 00:00:00.000 ║  0.000000 ║
║ A0002    ║ 20.000000 ║  457 ║ 15.000000 ║ 2018-06-11 00:00:00.000 ║ 15.000000 ║
║ A0002    ║ 20.000000 ║  458 ║ 25.000000 ║ 2018-06-11 00:00:00.000 ║  5.000000 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lamak!! funciona de 10, voy a hacer el caso con datos reales pero creo que debería andar OK; lo que me falta es que en caso de no haber saldo suficiente decuente en negativo del último lote, pero no te preocupes ya veo como resolverlo!